# JavaFX Combobox Custom control focus lost issue

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, custom-controls

I have Created a custom control call it `ComboBoxTablePopup` extending `Comboboxbase` class. I have used a tableview as a popup content. Everything works fine, 
update value, show popup, hide popup. After switching the focus from `ComboBoxTablePopup` to another control like a `TextField` or `Spinner`, it updates it self with null value.
So, I don't know what makes this happens. So here is my implementation on self executable class.

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.KeyBinding;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.WeakInvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;


public class TestComboboxTablePopup extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ComboBoxTablePopupControl<dataModel> comboBoxTablePopup = new ComboBoxTablePopupControl<>();
        TableColumn<dataModel, Integer> tcId = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        TableColumn<dataModel, String> tcName = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        tcId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<dataModel, Integer>("id"));
        tcName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<dataModel, String>("name"));

        comboBoxTablePopup.setColumns(FXCollections.observableArrayList(tcId, tcName));
        comboBoxTablePopup.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new dataModel(1, "Data Model object 1"),
                new dataModel(2, "Data Model object 2"),
                new dataModel(3, "Data Model object 3")
        ));

        VBox vBox = new VBox(comboBoxTablePopup);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public class dataModel {
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public dataModel(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    private static <S> StringConverter<S> defaultStringConverter() {
        return new StringConverter<S>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(S t) {
                return t == null ? "abood fait" : t.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public S fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }


    private class ComboBoxTablePopupControl<S> extends ComboBoxBase {


        /***************************************************************************
         * *
         * Static properties and methods                                           *
         * *
         **************************************************************************/

        private static final String DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS = "combobox-table-popup";


        private ObjectProperty<ObservableList<S>> items = new SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<S>>(this, "items");

        public final void setItems(ObservableList<S> value) {
            itemsProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final ObservableList<S> getItems() {
            return items.get();
        }

        public ObjectProperty<ObservableList<S>> itemsProperty() {
            return items;
        }


        public ObjectProperty<StringConverter<S>> converterProperty() {
            return converter;
        }

        private ObjectProperty<StringConverter<S>> converter =
                new SimpleObjectProperty<StringConverter<S>>(this, "converter", defaultStringConverter());

        public final void setConverter(StringConverter<S> value) {
            converterProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final StringConverter<S> getConverter() {
            return converterProperty().get();
        }


        // Editor
        private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<TextField> editor;

        public final TextField getEditor() {
            return editorProperty().get();
        }

        public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<TextField> editorProperty() {
            if (editor == null) {
                editor = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<TextField>(this, "editor");
                editor.set(new ComboBoxListViewSkin.FakeFocusTextField());
            }
            return editor.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }


        private
        ObservableList<TableColumn<S, ?>> columns = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public ObservableList<TableColumn<S, ?>> getColumns() {
            return columns;
        }

        public void setColumns(ObservableList<TableColumn<S, ?>> columns) {
            this.columns = columns;
        }


        /***************************************************************************
         *                                                                         *
         * Constructors                                                            *
         *                                                                         *
         **************************************************************************/

        /**
         * Creates a default ComboboxTablePopup instance with an empty
         * {@link #itemsProperty() items} list and default
         * {@link #selectionModelProperty() selection model}.
         */


        public ComboBoxTablePopupControl() {
            this(FXCollections.<S>emptyObservableList());

        }


        /**
         * Creates a default ComboboxTablePopup instance with the provided items list and
         * a default {   selection model}.
         */

        public ComboBoxTablePopupControl(ObservableList<S> items) {
            setItems(items);
            getStyleClass().add(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
            setEditable(true);
            valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                System.out.println(newValue);
            });


        }

        public ComboBoxTablePopupControl(ObservableList<S> items, ObservableList<TableColumn<S, ?>> columns) {
            this(items);
            this.columns = columns;

        }


        @Override
        protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
            return new ComboBoxTablePopupControlSkin<>(this);
        }


    }


    public class ComboBoxTablePopupControlSkin<S> extends ComboBoxPopupControl {

        private ComboBoxTablePopupControl comboBoxTablePopup;
        private ObservableList<S> comboboxTablePopupItems;

        private TableView<S> tableViewPopupContent;

        private ObservableList<S> tableViewPopupItems;


        private Predicate<S> predicate;

        private final InvalidationListener itemsObserver;

        private final ListChangeListener<S> tableViewItemsListener = new ListChangeListener<S>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends S> c) {
                getSkinnable().requestLayout();
            }
        };

        private final WeakListChangeListener<S> weakListViewItemsListener =
                new WeakListChangeListener<S>(tableViewItemsListener);


        public ComboBoxTablePopupControlSkin(ComboBoxTablePopupControl comboBoxTablePopup) {
            super(comboBoxTablePopup, new ComboBoxBaseBehavior(comboBoxTablePopup, null));
            this.comboBoxTablePopup = comboBoxTablePopup;


            updateComboBoxTablePopupItems();


            itemsObserver = observable -> {
                updateComboBoxTablePopupItems();
                updateTableViewItems();

            };
            this.comboBoxTablePopup.itemsProperty().addListener(new WeakInvalidationListener(itemsObserver));

            tableViewPopupContent = createTableView();
            tableViewPopupContent.setManaged(false);

            getChildren().add(tableViewPopupContent);


            updateTableViewItems();


            registerChangeListener(comboBoxTablePopup.converterProperty(), "CONVERTER");
            registerChangeListener(comboBoxTablePopup.itemsProperty(), "ITEMS");
            registerChangeListener(comboBoxTablePopup.valueProperty(), "VALUE");
            registerChangeListener(comboBoxTablePopup.editorProperty(), "EDITABLE");


        }

        private void updateTableViewItems() {
            this.tableViewPopupItems = comboBoxTablePopup.getItems();
            this.tableViewPopupContent.setItems(this.tableViewPopupItems);

            if (tableViewPopupItems != null) {
                tableViewPopupItems.removeListener(weakListViewItemsListener);
            }

            this.tableViewPopupItems = comboboxTablePopupItems;
            tableViewPopupContent.setItems(tableViewPopupItems);

            if (tableViewPopupItems != null) {
                tableViewPopupItems.addListener(weakListViewItemsListener);
            }


            getSkinnable().requestLayout();
        }


        public void updateComboBoxTablePopupItems() {
            comboboxTablePopupItems = comboBoxTablePopup.getItems();
            comboboxTablePopupItems = comboboxTablePopupItems == null ? FXCollections.<S>emptyObservableList() : comboboxTablePopupItems;

        }

        private TableView<S> createTableView() {
            final TableView<S> tableView = new TableView<>();

            tableView.setId("table-view");
             tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
            tableView.setFocusTraversable(false);

            for (TableColumn tblColumn : tableColumns()) {
                tableView.getColumns().add(tblColumn);
            }

            tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(o -> {
                S selectedItem = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                comboBoxTablePopup.setValue(selectedItem);

            });


            tableView.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER ||

                        e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {

                    S selectedItem = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    comboBoxTablePopup.setValue(selectedItem);
                    comboBoxTablePopup.hide();
                }

            });


            return tableView;
        }

        private ObservableList<TableColumn> tableColumns() {
            return ((ComboBoxTablePopupControl) getSkinnable()).getColumns();
        }

        @Override
        protected Node getPopupContent() {
            return this.tableViewPopupContent;
        }

        @Override
        protected TextField getEditor() {
            return ((ComboBoxTablePopupControl) getSkinnable()).getEditor();
        }

        @Override
        protected StringConverter<S> getConverter() {
            return ((ComboBoxTablePopupControl) getSkinnable()).getConverter();
        }

        @Override
        public Node getDisplayNode() {

            Node displayNode;
            displayNode = getEditableInputNode();


            updateDisplayNode();

            return displayNode;

        }

        @Override
        protected void handleControlPropertyChanged(String p) {


            if ("VALUE".equals(p)) {

                updateDisplayNode();
                System.out.println(comboBoxTablePopup.getValue());
                comboBoxTablePopup.fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
            } else if ("CONVERTER".equals(p)) {
                updateDisplayNode();
                System.out.println("Conveter  peroptery");
            } else if ("ITEMS".equals(p)) {

                updateComboBoxTablePopupItems();
                updateTableViewItems();
            } else if ("EDITOR".equals(p)) {
                getEditableInputNode();
            } else
                super.handleControlPropertyChanged(p);
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Wow, that's loads of code. It must be some point where the value of your control is set in the first place (or the data is bound to your control). Maybe you can point out how this happens or at least add an example on how to use your control in an example app - that might help to get started without investigating too much.

Comment: I have added a complete running example, please try it to figure out my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has trouble with this issue, here is a workaround for a choicebox. I assume you already have a table with columns and an `EventHandler`. This example is not tested with any **editable** (`isEditable(true)`) object.

First set a custom `Factory` and an EventHandler for `setOnEditStart`

```
yourColumn.setCellFactory(value -> new CustomEditFactory(yourObsList));
```

In your `CustomEditFactory` class you have to extend `TreeTableCell<KnotenObs, String>` and `@Override` four methods

**startEdit()**

```
@Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();         
        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(getItem());
        oldValue = choiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        setGraphic(choiceBox);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }
```

**commitEdit()**

```
@Override
    public void commitEdit(String newValue) {
        if(newValue == null) {
            super.commitEdit(oldValue);
        } else {
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
        }
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }
```

**cancelEdit()**

```
@Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        if(getItem() == null) {
            setText(oldValue);
        } else {
            setText(getItem());
        }
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }
```

**updateItem()**

```
@Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        if(item == null) {
            super.updateItem(oldValue, empty);
            setText(oldValue);
        } else {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item);
        }  
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }
```